# count total rows returned by query in doctrine 2 zf2

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

```
$countQuery = $qb->select('q.id,d.name,d.numbers')
            ->from('Application\Entity\quests', 'q');
            ->leftJoin('q.dots', 'd');
$query1 = $countQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
```

now how would i get the total number of results returned 
`**i don't want to write 2 queries**` bcz it will increase the execution time than
i have tried

```
 $countQuery = $qb->select('count(q.id) as total_results,d.name,d.numbers')
            ->from('Application\Entity\quests', 'q');
            ->leftJoin('q.dots', 'd');
$query1 = $countQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getResult()` method returns an array of results. To count total results returned by `getResult()` method simply count it with PHP function [count](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.count.php).

```
$countQuery = $qb
    ->select('q.id,d.name,d.numbers)
    ->from('Application\Entity\quests', 'q')
    ->leftJoin('q.dots', 'd');

$query1 = $countQuery->getQuery()->getResult();

$totalResults = count($query1);
```

If you want to paginate your query then in case of counting total rows you need to execute two queries. One for paginated results and other to count all rows in the database.

Comment: it is returning *["count_id"]=> string(1) "1"* with each array but i want it to return the total number of results

Comment: if i am returning 100 rows it should say 100 rows

Comment: Also `getResult()` return an array so you can simple call `count ($query1);` to get amount of returnet results instead of adding `count query`

Comment: yeah i am doing it now but if i want to count query how would i do that